# Unit test cases in go

Tags: unit-testing, go, testing, service

I am writing unit test cases for the simple service. I am trying to write test case for error condition for Run function. How can I write the test case for the s.Run error condition.

```
     type AgentService struct{}
        enter code here
    
    var serviceNew = service.New
    var runtimeGOOS = runtime.GOOS

func (A *AgentService) Start(s service.Service) error {
    fmt.Println(s.String() + " started")

    go run()
    return nil
}

func run() {
    for {
        fmt.Println("Service is running...")
        time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
    }
}

func StartService() error {
    AgentConfig := &service.Config{
        Name:        gServiceName,
        DisplayName: gDisplayName,
        Description: gServiceDescription,
    }

    Agservice := &AgentService{}
    s, err := serviceNew(Agservice, AgentConfig)
    if err != nil {
        logs.Error("Failed to create service: %v", err)
        return err
    }

    err = s.Run()
    if err != nil {
        logs.Error("Failed to start service: %v", err)
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Please provide more of your code. What is the s.Run function?

Comment: btw, one way that I can think of is that you need to write tests for all functions in StartService separately, then mock them and write test for StartService.

Comment: Yes I have mocked other functions and test it

Comment: This is whole code exept the imported packages and main function where I have called the Startservice

Comment: In s.Run s is for service and Run is inbuilt function to starts the service